# Как на гитхабе отредактировать данный элемент?(скрин внутри)

Tags: github

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

В работе используется react и другие вещи, хотелось бы что бы они здесь отображались

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Гитхаб определяет язык автоматически при помощи библиотеки [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist).
В случае если язык определяется неверно, можно создать файл `.gitattributes` и указать в нём язык напрямую:

```
# Example of a `.gitattributes` file which reclassifies `.rb` files as Java:
*.rb linguist-language=Java
```

Обратите внимание, что речь идёт только о языке, на котором написан проект. В этом разделе не указывается фреймворк или какое-то произовольное слово.

[image: Пример репозиториев на гитхабе]

Ключевые слова проекта принято указывать в темах, которые находятся сразу после краткого описания проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того чтоб отредактировать темы проекта, нужно нажать "Manage topics":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]